# Keeping old values of variable in constructor in qt and cpp

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt and Cpp (on windows 10). I have a situation in my application. The application is a Falling Ball game. Basically, the game is that balls keeps on falling at regular intervals of 3 secs. There is a rectangle that acts as a basket to catch the ball. I have defined the dimensions of the ball and basket in the Sprite class as shown below. My question is, as I have sprites being created at regular intervals, the dimensions of the BAR(rectangular basket x1 and y1) are defined in the Sprite constructor. Whenever I create a new sprite every 3 secs, the default values of x1 and y1 are set ignoring the current values obtained by the position of the basket. How can I keep the old values of x1 and y1, while creating new sprites at regular intervals?

### Sprite.h

```
int x=0;//position of sprite in x-direction.

    int y=0;//position of sprite in y-direction.

    int dx=1;//difference in x-direction position.

    int dy=1;//difference in y-direction position.

     int x1=0;//position of the basket in x-direction

     int y1=0   ;//position of the basket in y-direction.
```

### Sprite.cpp

```
Sprite::Sprite(QWidget *p)
{
    parent=p;
    QRect rct = parent->rect();
    x = rand() % rct.width();//randomly initialize the x-position for the sprite.
    y=rct.height()*0.05;//start position for the sprite is about 5% after the top of the menu bar.

    dx = rand() % 10;//the speed is randomly set in x-direction.    
    dy = 4;

    x1=rct.width()/2;
    y1 = rct.height() - 80;
    start(10);
}


void Sprite::drawBall(QPainter &painter)
{
    painter.drawEllipse(x, y, 15, 15);
}

void Sprite::drawBar(QPainter &painter)
{
    painter.drawRect( x1, y1, 80, 30);
}

void Sprite::move(int nDirection)
{
    QRect rct = parent->rect();
    if(nDirection == 0)
    {
        if(x1 >= 0 )             x1 += -15;
    }
    else
    {
        if(x1+80 < rct.width()){x1 += 15;}
    }
}

void Sprite::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
     QRect rct = parent->rect();
    if ( x > rct.width() || x < 0)
        dx *= -1;
    if ( y > rct.height() || y < 0)
        dy *= 1;
     if (event->timerId() == timerId1)
     {
        qDebug() << "Timer ID:" << event->timerId();
     }

    x += dx;
    y += dy;

         if( (((y - 15) >= 520)&& y <550 ) && ( (x <= (x1 + 80)) && (x >= (x1 - 80)) ))
        {
            qDebug("x and y position when condition is met and also x1 and y1");
            qDebug()<<x;
            qDebug()<<y;
            qDebug()<<x1;
            qDebug()<<y1;
            dy *= -1;
            dx *= -1;
        }    
    parent->update();
}
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() <<"mainWindow constructor";    
     QTimer *timer;    
     timer=new QTimer(this);
      connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::onTimer);
     timer->start(3000);    
}

void MainWindow::onTimer()
{
    sprite = new Sprite(this);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::draw, sprite, &Sprite::drawBall);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. I think you're saying that every instance of Sprite wants to store its own copy of the position of the Bar. That design doesn't make much sense to me. But if you made the values static members, then there would only be a single copy shared between all instances of Sprite.

Comment: As I have these two properties x1=rct.width()/2;
    y1 = rct.height() - 80; in the constructor of Sprite. At every 3 secs, this constructor is called and x1 and y1 values are set the values defined in the constructor. How and where should I define these variables (x1 and y1) so that they maintain the values of moving the basket even though the constructor is called.

Comment: If I use static variables where can I initialize its values

Comment: Like I said, this design doesn't make much sense. Don't change the Bar's position from the Sprite's constructor. You initialize static variables outside of any function in the .cpp file. But it sounds like what you really need is a separate Bar object to maintain its own position regardless of what Sprite does.

Comment: can we use extern keywork for this

Comment: `extern` has no relevance in this context. That's for accessing variables declared in other .cpp files. Your problem is you're redeclaring your variables with every new instance of Sprite. Making them static will prevent that. But it's still a bad design.